# Error updating by Model Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having trouble in my project . I can't update by Model but i use sql statement code run normal. Please see and help me .
Error :

```
            $data = array(
                'page_ord'=>$key+1;
            );
            if(!PageModel::where('page_key','=',"'".$value."'")->update($data))
            {
                return false;
            }
```

And Run normal :

```
            $ord = $key+1;
            $sql = "UPDATE tbl_pages SET page_ord = '".$ord."' WHERE page_key = '".$value."'";
            if(!\DB::statement($sql))
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Thank you!!
ps : My project using Laravel Framework

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: No Error but Update always return false @CodingInsane

Comment: Run this after you try to update and let us the message: `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: if your model name is `Page` and it's in `app/models/page.php` you should call it like `!Page::where('page_key','=',$value)` no need to add qoutes as well

Comment: try without quotes                       PageModel::where('page_key','=',$value)->update($data)

Comment: Thank you @CodingInsane . But qoutes i forget delete after test. No qoutes code still return false :(

Comment: @MrLinhK are you sure your model name is `PageModel` ? or it's just `Page`

Comment: @Jari : It return :
  array(3) {
    ["query"]=>
    string(58) "update `tbl_pages` set `page_ord` = ? where `page_key` = ?"
    ["bindings"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      string(32) "e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a31222"
    }
    ["time"]=>
    float(1.08)
  }

Comment: @CodingInsane : Yes . Im sure

Comment: Have you set your table name in PageModel                                              protected $table="tbl_pages"

Comment: @GaneshJogam : Yes . i have 2 function call that code . 1 function run nomarl , 1 function error . :(

Comment: Is your $data array is correct first try printing it

Comment: If it is right test with the echo statement to check the object count    echo count(PageModel::where('page_key','=',"'".$value."'")->get());    it should return one

Comment: @GaneshJogam : yes it return 1 . I post full my code below . Please see and help me

Comment: it is not showing error right it is not updating values then post model class

Comment: and why are you returning in a loop

Comment: Yes . I post full code in below . I return in loop for rollback if error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//First find object by using id as 
$page = PageModel::where('page_key','=',$value)->first();
// then add field value which you want to update
$page->page_ord = $key +1;
// update 
$page->save();
```

Comment: Thank you . It work . But i want know why my code return false :(